# Is the output of the C code below different depending on platforms?

Tags: c, printf

The C code is below. I know the code will cause core dump. What is the output we can see? Is it different for different platforms?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("abc\n123");
    printf("IHJ");
    printf("%d", int* 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's platform independent. It does not compile on any platform.

Comment: What is `int* 0` supposed to do?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It generates a compiler error.

Comment: @Olaf I believe the OP has a different opinion.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   It would get error.

Comment: @Olaf  This is a question I got in an exam.

Comment: @ChongZheng Of course it would. It's syntax error. So no core dump is expected.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   Oh... the interviewer told me core dump...

Comment: Good example of interviewer not knowing the subject properly. But you might have missed the parenthesis for a cast here. Check the code above again! Is that **exactly** what he showed you??

Comment: @Olaf  Oh... the interviewer told me core dump...

Comment: Are you sure that is the exam code, and you're not remembering it a bit wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> ***I know the code will cause core dump***

Well, sadly, your information is *wrong*. **The above code will not compile**. Read on.

There is an issue in your code with the third `printf()`.

```
  printf("%d", int* 0);
```

is not valid and it won't compile. `%d` expects an `int` **variable**, not the `int` keyoword itself.

Even if, that `int*` is *meant* to be a `cast`, like

```
printf("%d", (int*)0);
```

it's wrong, also. You'll need `%p` to print a pointer (address). Supplying invalid type of argument for a particular format specifier  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, when you face UB, you ***might*** get a segmentation fault and a core-dump.

Otherwise, as long as you supply the required type and number of arguments to the format specifiers supplied with `printf()`, you'll have a well-defined behaviour.

To be pedantic, `int main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: I start being not so sure about function in C requiring `void` for an empty argument list anymore. Still use it, but might that have changed in a later standard? You know: approach C++ a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d", int* 0);
```

This will not compile. If you meant

```
printf("%d", (int*)0);
```

then it's also wrong (using wrong format specifier is *undefined behaviour*) since the format specifier for printing a pointer is `%p`. So you meant

```
printf("%p", (void*) (int*)0);
```

Then the resulting representation printed by `%p` is implementation defined.

C standard states

**C11, 7.21.6  Formatted input/output functions**

> The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner.

Comment: I have a question here. 0 is constant. If ((int*) 0) return the address of constant value 0?

Comment: @ChongZheng No. ((int*) 0) returns a pointer of type int* which points to address 0.

Comment: @TomCarpenter It's true for the most cases, but I am not sure the standard would guarantee it...

Comment: You do not have to cast a pointer to `void *`. and you should actually not.

Comment: @Olaf The standard mandates so (as quoted in my answer for `%p`). There's no implicit conversion from `int*` to `void*` since printf is a variadic function. So the cast is necessary.

Comment: @Olaf: this is one of the few places where an explicit cast to `void *` is required (in the sense that if you don't, the behavior is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

If the third `printf()` had the exact for as shown:

```
printf("%d", int* 0);
```

This will result in a compiler error. If, however, you meant

```
printf("%d", (int *)0);
```

The there are two problems:

- The format specifier is for an integer, not a pointer. If both have the same size, you will luckily get the same output. But it actually is undefined behaviour. Use `"%p"` for pointers.
- Annother problem (and more general) is that you are passing a [null pointer](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3). As the whole treatment of pointers is *implementation specific*, your `printf()` might handle it differently from *valid pointer values*.

Either way, it is not guaranted to core dump or show any specific behaviour. It might even **show** no errorneous behaviour (worst case - you do not notice something went wrong). The essence of "undefined behaviour" is that **anything can happen**. Your computer might fly away.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to print a null pointer with `%p`. It's not *undefined*; null pointer *is* a valid pointer.

Comment: *Annother problem (and more general) is that you are passing a null pointer, which results in undefined behaviour. printf is only defined to print valid pointers which the null pointer by definition is not* is incorrect. Only the representation of null pointer is implementation defined; printing it using printf is defined by the standard.

Comment: It talks about *invalid value* as in `char *p=0; printf("%s", p);`, `strcpy(p, "hello");` etc, not the case we talk about here.

Comment: I didn't say using variable changes behaviour as opposed to using a literal. I just gave examples for *invalid value*. I have indeed read the whole passage. Nothing said there disproves what I said.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned before,

```
printf( "%d", int* 0 );
```

will not compile, as `int* 0` is not a legal expression.

If written as

```
printf ( "%d", (int *) 0 );
```

then the behavior is *undefined*, since `%d` expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`, not `int *`. This will most likely *not* cause a core dump, but any output should not be trusted.

If written as

```
printf( "%p", (int *) 0 );
```

the the behavior is *still* undefined, since `%p` expects a `void *` (this is one of the few places where you need to explicitly cast a pointer value to `void *` in C).  Again, this will most likely *not* cause a core dump, but any output should not be trusted.

If written as

```
printf( "%p", (void *) 0 );
```

then it should print out the implementation-defined value for a NULL pointer, which may not or may not be 0 (assuming you follow that up with a newline or a call to `fflush( stdout )`, anyway).

If written as

```
printf( "%d", *(int *) 0 );
```

then this *will most likely* cause a core dump.  Strictly speaking, the behavior is still undefined since you are dereferencing an invalid pointer, and there may be systems where doing so won't result in an immediate crash.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very detailed.